# Twitter bootstrap popovers close when opening new

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm not JavaScript wizard, so I'm missing something obvious here I'm sure. I have a table that has multiple links utilizing **[Twitter Bootstrap's pop-over behavior](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)**. I have it where clicking on a link opens the pop-over, and clicking another closes the first, but it becomes glitchy after a few tries, and even starts to close itself. So the question is: **How do you properly make pop-overs close once another is opened?**

I set up a JSFiddle here (although it doesn't seem to be working at all): http://jsfiddle.net/ZnJ6b/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Button</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item #1</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn show-text" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Content for item one." title="" data-original-title="Review text">Click for text</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item #2</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn show-text" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Content for item two." title="" data-original-title="Review text">Click for text</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(this).popover('show');
$('.show-text').click(function () {
    $('.show-text').popover('hide');
});
```

**Thanks in advance for your help to a poor JS n00b!**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.show-text').popover();
$('.show-text').click(function () {
     $('.show-text').not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I had tried this early, and just did again. This actually seems to make it not open at all. No JS error messages, just doesn't open the pop-over.

Comment: That will actually just keep opening the pop-overs, but does not close any others.

Comment: Ok, that was close. This is actually working for me: $('.show-text').popover();
 $('.show-text').click(function () {
  $('.show-text').not(this).popover('hide');
 });