# Close all open Bootstrap popovers created via delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scenario with Bootstrap Popovers (version 2.3 although I can recreate the issue in 3 as well) where I have multiple popovers on the page and I want to be able to close any open popovers when a new one is opened.

The method I have (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426726/twitter-bootstrap-popovers-close-when-opening-new)) to close open popovers works fine until I initialize my popovers using the `selector` option which delegates the popover objects.

Here's the JS:

```
// Works if popovers are instantiated this way
//$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();

// Doesn't work if popovers are instantiated this way
var options = { selector: '[data-toggle=popover]' };

$(".container").popover(options)

$("[data-toggle=popover]").click(function() {
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="Popover Title">Click to see my popover.</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="Popover Title">Click to see my popover.</a>
</div>
```

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/0xzVVvxJ83)

I've spent some time digging through the source code and I see what the issue might be, but I'm not sure how to work around this.  Has anyone made something like this work before?

Update:

This does work - `$("[data-toggle=popover]").filter(this).popover('show');` - My only concern is this block of code from the popover library:

```
function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.popover')
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option

      if (!data && option == 'destroy') return
      if (!data) $this.data('bs.popover', (data = new Popover(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }
```

The line

`if (!data) $this.data('bs.popover', (data = new Popover(this, options)))`

adds a data attribute to `.container` when the popover is init'ed initially using the `selector` option, but then when

`$("[data-toggle=popover]").not(this).popover('hide');`

is called it loops through each element that matches the `$("[data-toggle=popover]")` selector and re-inits a popover on each element it finds, ignoring the fact that a popover object was already added to the parent container and set to work via delegation using the selector option.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and - in my opinion - the best way to do that, is to use `<button>` instead of `<a>` and then use the `focus` trigger.

```
var options = { selector: '[data-toggle=popover]', trigger: 'focus' };

$(".container").popover(options);



<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="Popover Title">Click to see my popover.</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="Popover Title">Click to see my popover.</button>
</div>
```

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/2w4cufVaow)

If you don't want/can't change the anchors, you can try that:

```
var options = { selector: '[data-toggle=popover]' };

$("body").popover(options)

$("[data-toggle=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('shown');
});

$("body").on('click', '[data-toggle=popover]', function(e) {
   $('.shown').not(this).popover('hide').removeClass('shown');
});
```

Here is another [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Vc3hDOfA2H).

Comment: Nice!  Unfortunately, in this instance I'm not able to switch my anchors to buttons so this approach does not seem to work.

Comment: I added a solution maintaining the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript hides the other popovers just fine... but you forgot to open the new one!

```
var options = { selector: '[data-toggle=popover]' };

$(".container").popover(options);

$("[data-toggle=popover]").click(function() {
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").not(this).popover('hide');
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").this.popover('show');
});
```

Disclosure: I actually don't know what I'm doing, but when I checked the Bootstrap documentation and ran this in Bootply it appears to create the behavior you are looking for.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/81C8ZxVG2S)

Comment: This actually causes an error in the console since `$("[data-toggle=popover]").this` is undefined.  However, it gave me the idea of using $("[data-toggle=popover]").filter(this).popover('show') which does work.  There is still an issue with this approach that I will update my question to reflect.

Comment: This solution seems to work because javascript throws and error and stops working midway. But that will mean that any other javascript after that line will not be triggered either.